# Directing user to the indiviudal aircraft.html subpages onto my main webview home page.html, when pressing on title

Tags: database, macos, http, https, replit

[current fleet main title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKQ26.png)
https://replit.com/@zhao-zhunzhun/China-Southern-fleet-website-2#templates/home.html
https://2ccda84c-60ca-4689-ae64-064bab98f537-00-2wl8c7h36mvsw.riker.replit.dev/
Basically, you could see that I have a main section of "Fleet", and respectively other sections such as A319ceo.html, A320ceo.html included within the aircraft-model folder.

My current issue is that, on replit with app.py, I can't get my external aircraft.html links connected to the title currently listed on the main webwiew (home.html), and I really need to link the individual aircraft subpages to the title listed ob webview, and I don't know how could I achieve it.

Therefore, could the Stack overflow community assist me in linking aircraft.html to the main title link on the home.html (main webview)

I tried edditing app.py with:

```py
@app.route('/A319ceo')
def a319ceo():
    return render_template('A319ceo.html')
```

Is it an HTML 550 error with no server? But didn't I def A319ceo so that it can redirect to A319ceo.html on the "A319ceo" link on the main website?